# Help with choosing appropriate model strategy, time series regression involving ratios

Tags: time-series, outliers, beta-regression

I've been stuck on a particular problem for quite some time and have tried several ARIMA based approaches, some involving exogenous regressors. If you like you can see some of my recent threads to get a better idea of what I've been trying to accomplish. After examining respective series for stationarity, trying various pre-whitening approaches to identify meaningful relationships, and building various iterations of the model, I thought that I had possibly identified a useful model but comparing training vs test data resulted in very poor predictions. After researching further, I think my issue might be due to a lack of understanding of the potential issues surrounding time series regression when ratios/proportions are the dependent variable. I'm interested in exploring beta regression and have been studying https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf as well as https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3533.pdf for time series applications. I thought it might be a good idea to spell out exactly what I'm trying to accomplish prior to diving too deeply into this method in order to see if this is even a feasible approach.

The Data:

The time series of interest are cash flow to equity holders (CFE) and operating earnings (OE). What I am interested in forecasting is the ratio of OE distributed as CFE over time (CFE/OE). I think this data might be appropriately modeled as a long term mean reverting series impacted by more near term exogenous effects (OE level or growth in OE). I know introducing OE (the denominator of the ratio to be modeled) as an exogenous variable raises some potential red flags however, I think there is sufficient economic rationale to justify it being included as an exogenous regressor; the ratio being modeled represents the cash return to shareholders as a proportion of current period's earnings and I believe that the current level of those earnings (or growth rate) influences the proportion distributed by way of sentiment. Essentially, if times are good(bad) firms are more(less) comfortable returning a particular amount of those earnings. I actually believe that the correlation between OE and CFE/OE is likely to be negative but I'm just explaining my logic for wanting to include the denominator on both sides.

Peculiarities with the data:

As mentioned, I'd like to explore beta regression models as I'm interested in trying to forecast (CFE/OE) given any mean reverting structure as well as the impacts of short term operating performance (the OE themselves). The first sticking point I can foresee in this type of approach is the fact that the ratio can exceed 1 in the short term. I know that beta regression assumes that the response variable be bounded on the (0,1) interval. I'm wondering if there is a method or transformation available to address the case where this may not hold in the short term but can assumed to be true in the long term? The ratio can exceed one in a given period because periodic CFE isn't a strict function of the period's OE. Firms can hoard cash and distribute these when they think it is beneficial to do so allowing for distributions that exceed OE (debt issuances and other things can be used for the same purpose). In the long term however, OE will eventually be a limiting factor for shareholder disbursements. I should point out that OE are just the particular accounting measure I've chosen, there are a variety of earnings metrics that could be used assuming they can be reconciled to a relevant cash flow figure. I initially thought that I could maybe scale the figures by the largest data point, effectively setting the max to 1 but after thinking about this more it seemed like I would be arbitrarily setting the 'cap' when in reality I don't know the maximum, only that it cannot remain above 1 in perpetuity. Along the same lines, what if anything can be done for potential outlier periods when the ratio is negative? Setting these to zero seems odd since cash was still distributed to investors during these periods despite negative operating results. Would it be possible to treat these as 'NA' values and fill them in via some kind of interpolation?

I'm eager for any feed back or suggestions. I've posted the data sets in previous posts but am more than happy to add it here if you think it is beneficial, although I'm more interested in understanding if my approach is even theoretically sounds.

Comment: A beta distribution would be appropriate for $A/(A+B)$ if you have non-negative $A$ and $B$ which can be modeled as gamma distributed (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions)). In this case the ratio $A/B$ would be [beta-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties) distributed. If $A$ and/or $B$ can be negative, then at best you could use these approaches for the *magnitudes* $|A|,|B|$, conditioned on their *signs* (which would have to be modeled separately, e.g. as Bernoulli).

Comment: What about modelling the expected ratio (or maybe the ratio of expectations? ) by starting with a bivariate/vector GLM, for instance as implemented in R, VGAM package?  That way you keep the individual variables, and information about their variance.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I'll need to do quite a bit of reading to become more familiar with GLM concepts. I'm starting to wonder if a better approach might be to abandon the idea of modeling the IV as a ratio and instead model the LN(CFE) as a function of OE growth ( or lags of) with ARMA errors. Although, as I'm learning more about potential weaknesses of linear models I'm wondering if this approach will lead to others issues. Even if OE growth is say, normal, couldn't I still run into issues where a period's OE growth is so large and negative that it would predict negative CFE values?

Comment: Would it be possible to overcome such an issue by simply including an additional regressor being an indicator variable for whether or not growth was positive or negative?